# NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.messaging' in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-web

I got the error (this one didn't bring the error screen for my run
web application, which I stumbled upon while inspecting the debug console) `NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.messaging'`.

Here is my debug console:

```
NoSuchMethodError: tried to call a non-function, such as null: 'dart.global.firebase.messaging'
packages/firebase_messaging_web/src/interop/messaging.dart 21:26                         getMessagingInstance
packages/firebase_messaging_web/firebase_messaging_web.dart 28:27                        get [_delegate]
packages/firebase_messaging_web/firebase_messaging_web.dart 109:5                        getToken
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                       runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5                       _async
packages/firebase_messaging_web/firebase_messaging_web.dart 108:27                       getToken
packages/firebase_messaging/src/messaging.dart 117:22                                    getToken
packages/hello_world/......
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 84:54                       runBody
dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/async_patch.dart 123:5                       _async
packages/hello_world/......
packages/hello_world/......  <fn>
packages/riverpod/src/common.dart 524:24                                                 <fn>
packages/riverpod/src/common.dart 283:16                                                 map
packages/riverpod/src/common.dart 523:12                                                 AsyncValueX.when
packages/hello_world/......
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4876:22                                      build
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4806:15                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4883:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4883:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5154:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5154:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5825:32                                      updateChildren
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6375:17                                      update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5009:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5154:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5009:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6222:14                                      update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5154:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 6222:14                                      update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5009:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5009:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5154:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5154:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5009:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5154:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 5009:5                                       update
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 3530:14                                      updateChild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4832:16                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4977:11                                      performRebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 4529:5                                       rebuild
packages/flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart 2659:18                                      buildScope
packages/flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart 891:9                                          drawFrame
packages/flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart 370:5                                        [_handlePersistentFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1146:15                                      [_invokeFrameCallback]
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 1083:9                                       handleDrawFrame
packages/flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart 997:5                                        [_handleDrawFrame]
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 1090:13                                      invoke
lib/_engine/engine/platform_dispatcher.dart 160:5                                        invokeOnDrawFrame
lib/_engine/engine/initialization.dart 194:45                                            <fn>
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1442:13                                                     _rootRunUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1335:19                                                     runUnary
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1244:7                                                      runUnaryGuarded
dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1281:26                                                     <fn>
```

I googled and read some Stack Overflow questions, but their errors are not relevant to me. The last sentence in their error is not `dart.global.firebase.messaging`.

How can I fix this error? Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. When I updated [`firebase_messaging`](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) to a newer version, this error went away!